# Memory banks unbalanced

Tags: memory, hp, central-processing-unit

My team and I at work have inherited 2 X G7 DL380's.  From looking over the iLO I can see that the memory setup is odd.

```
PROC 1 DIMM 1G    Not installed
PROC 1 DIMM 2D  2048 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 1 DIMM 3A  4096 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 1 DIMM 4H    Not installed
PROC 1 DIMM 5E  2048 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 1 DIMM 6B  4096 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 1 DIMM 7I    Not installed
PROC 1 DIMM 8F    Not installed
PROC 1 DIMM 9C  4096 MB 1333 MHz


PROC 2 DIMM 1G    Not installed
PROC 2 DIMM 2D  2048 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 2 DIMM 3A  4096 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 2 DIMM 4H    Not installed
PROC 2 DIMM 5E  2048 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 2 DIMM 6B  4096 MB 1333 MHz
PROC 2 DIMM 7I    Not installed
PROC 2 DIMM 8F    Not installed
PROC 2 DIMM 9C  4096 MB 1333 MHz
```

If I'm reading this correctly ... It appears all channels are populated evenly but there are 2 X 2GB DIMMs missing from Ch 3 bank 2 (8F).  Will this be detrimental to overall performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is fine. If the server boots, it's an acceptable configuration.